# How do I run nvim-qt from the appImage?

Tags: neovim

I downloaded nvim.appimage v0.9.1 to run on `KDE neon 22.04 5.27 base: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Jammy`. In the terminal, so far, so good.

However, looking at the `nvim.appimage --help` and also at `:help`, I haven't found how to run nvim-qt. How can I run nvim-qt?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** To answer the questions to comments so far: I figured that since `nvim-qt` is installed alongside `nvim` when I install Neovim from the package manager, that it would come along with the appimage, too. I installed the appimage because the Ubuntu repo is still on Neovim 0.6.x.

I had hoped to find an option to pass in the cli invocation in the --help or in the :help, but I did not.

I found the `--appimage-mount` option, so I was able to inspect the contents of the appimage. I don't see `nvim-qt` in the `bin` directory, so it seems that I'm looking for something that isn't there.

Comment: Welcome to vi SE. What have you tried so far? What did you expect? What did actually happen? Please [edit] and tell us.

Comment: What makes you think, nvim-qt is part of the Neovim Appimage?

Comment: So... is your issue solved? Frankly, I don't get what the question is about and the edit didn't help much. It might be just me being stupid. I still don't get the *aim* behind your actions. I presume you want to run a GUI version of Neovim. Is that what you're trying to do? Is it working? See [How to ask?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase my question. I want to run the GUI version of Neovim. Is that possible from `nvim.appimage`?